# Route the path of the script depending on the button pressed mshta.exe vbscript:Execute

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

In a batch file I can get the following to give me a message box with an 'ok' button

```
mshta.exe vbscript:Execute^("msgbox ""Registers NOT submitted""& VbCrLf & VbCrLf &""Tap or click 'Ok' to exit"",vbexclamation,""Please check your internet connection"":close"^)
```

I can add yes no buttons thus;

```
mshta.exe vbscript:Execute^("msgbox ""Registers NOT submitted""& VbCrLf & VbCrLf &""Tap or click 'Ok' to exit"",VBYesNo,""Please check your internet connection"":close"^)
```

What I need to do is to route the path of the rest of the script depending on which button they pressed - yes / no. Is this possible without referencing an external .vbs?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not easily, no.  The HTA implementation of neither VBScript nor JScript offers a native way to produce an exit code.  You could possibly find the process object corresponding to the HTA instance then use that object's `.Terminate` method to exit non-zero (as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20823905/1683264)); or possibly have the HTA conditionally write a temporary file or store a registry value.  But all of those choices involve leaving the world of the graceful one-liner and you might as well use a [hybrid script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28323433/1683264) which *does* recognize commands to exit non-zero.

If a tidy one-liner is what you're after, you might have better luck with PowerShell:

```js
powershell "add-type -As System.Windows.Forms; exit([windows.forms.messagebox]::show(\"Registers NOT submitted.`n`nDo you want to continue?\",'Warning',4))"
```

That will exit status 6 for "Yes", 7 for "No".  So basically...

```js
if errorlevel 7 (
    rem // user chose "No"
    exit /b
) else (
    rem // user chose "Yes"
    goto begin
)
```

The argument of "4" in that `[windows.forms.messagebox]::show` method can be any of the following values:

```
0 -- OK
1 -- OK Cancel
2 -- Abort Retry Ignore
3 -- Yes No Cancel
4 -- Yes No
5 -- Retry Cancel
```

The buttons result in the following exit codes:

```
OK = errorlevel 1
Cancel = errorlevel 2
Abort = errorlevel 3
Retry = errorlevel 4
Ignore = errorlevel 5
Yes = errorlevel 6
No = errorlevel 7
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution and clear explanation!  :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to use a temporary file that holds the index of the clicked button.

Since this extends also the VBScript portion (due to the file creation code), I decided to place it in the batch script directly after the batch code. To identify it, every line is preceded with `//`. (Regard that line continuation `_` cannot be used there; environment variables like `%TEMP%` cannot be used also.)

In the batch script portion, the VBScript lines are read by `findstr /R "^//"` and a `for /F` loop, all lines of the VBScript code are appended to each other, using separator `:`. (Regard the limitation of command line length of about 8190 characters, which must not be exceeded by the entire VBScript.)

After having executed the `mshta VBScript:Execute^("!SCRIPT!"^)` command line, the index of the clicked `MsgBox` button is read from the temporary file (which is deleted immediately afterwards). Then the button name is displayed and the `ErrorLevel` is set to the button index just for demonstration.

So here is the full code including some explanatory comments (save it with extension `.bat` or `cmd`):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem /* Define constants here: */
set "BUTTON[1]=OK"
set "BUTTON[2]=Cancel"
set "BUTTON[3]=Abort"
set "BUTTON[4]=Retry"
set "BUTTON[5]=Ignore"
set "BUTTON[6]=Yes"
set "BUTTON[7]=No"

rem /* Read VBScript portion which is everything with leading `//`
rem    (see the very bottom of this batch file): */
set "SCRIPT=" & set "SEP="
for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /R "^//" "%~f0"') do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "LINE=!LINE:*//=!"
    set ^"LINE=!LINE:^"=""!^" & rem "
    for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%S in ("!SCRIPT!!SEP!!LINE!") do (
        endlocal
        set "SCRIPT=%%S"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
    endlocal
    set "SEP=: "
)

rem /* Execute VBScript here in the parent directory of this batch file;
rem    this directory is going to contain a temporary text file then: */
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd /D "%~dp0"
mshta VBScript:Execute^("!SCRIPT!"^)
endlocal

rem /* Read the button index from the temporary text file and display: */
< "%~dp0msgbox_return_button.txt" set /P "INDEX="
del "%~dp0msgbox_return_button.txt"
call echo Button %%BUTTON[%INDEX%]%% ^(%INDEX%^) has been pressed.

rem /* Set `ErrorLevel` to the button index just as an example: */
cmd /C exit %INDEX%

endlocal
exit /B


/* VBScript */

//Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
//Set objTXT = objFSO.CreateTextFile(objFSO.BuildPath(objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName("."), "msgbox_return_button.txt"), True)
//objTXT.WriteLine(MsgBox("Please let me know:" & vbCrLf & "Is my answer helpful?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "StackOverflow"))
//objTXT.Close
//Close
```

Comment: Thank you for spending time on helping to find a solution - I really appreciate the time and trouble you have taken!