# How can I make this batch file respond to the answer given in the vbs pop up?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I want to make this `.bat` file to read the answer given on the newly made `.vbs` file (yes or a no question).

I don't know any solutions right now

```
echo x=msgbox("By performing this action you will lose access to the Vault, however you can regain access using the Vault Key. Are you sure you want to lock the Vault?" ,vbYesNo, "Lock Confirmation") >> msgbox.vbs

start msgbox.vbs

if msgbox=vbYes goto LOCK

else goto End
```

This results in the program to not enter the next steps and end

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978957/route-the-path-of-the-script-depending-on-the-button-pressed-mshta-exe-vbscript)

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
echo x=msgbox("By performing this action you will lose access to the Vault, however you can regain access using the Vault Key. Are you sure you want to lock the Vault?" ,vbYesNo, "Lock Confirmation") > msgbox.vbs
ECHO WScript.echo x>>msgbox.vbs

FOR /f %%a IN ('cscript msgbox.vbs') DO SET response=%%a

IF %response%==6 (ECHO "Yes" button selected)
IF %response%==7 (ECHO "No" button selected)
GOTO :EOF
```

This worked for me.

Why `6` and `7` ? Beats me.