# How to play Invisible Music in a Batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, audio

I was making a batch Music Player, but I can't play Invisible Music. I have tried this:

```
@echo off
:1
echo Hello
pause
goto 2
:2
start /min wmplayer "C:\Users\*user\Desktop\Games\Music.wav" 
goto 1
```

But it doesn't show up minimized. How can I start `wmplayer` minimized?

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23313709/play-invisible-music-with-batch-file/23316395#23316395

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
set file=track12.mp3
( echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
  echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
  echo Sound.Controls.play
  echo do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
  echo wscript.sleep 100
  echo loop
  echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000) >sound.vbs
start /min sound.vbs
```

just change `track12.mp3` with the name of your audio file

Comment: put the question as answered please

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this

Answer (score 2):

And here is a complete batch source for a batch Music Player ! So enjoy it ;)

**Batch Music Player.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set vbsfile=%temp%\Intro.vbs
Set URL=http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Intro_DJ.mp3
Call:Play %URL% %vbsfile%
Start %vbsfile%
Set MyFile=%~f0
Set ShorcutName=DJ Batch Music Player
(
echo Call Shortcut("%MyFile%","%ShorcutName%"^)
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************^)
echo Sub Shortcut(CheminApplication,Nom^)
echo    Dim objShell,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab
echo    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
echo    MyTab = Split(CheminApplication,"\"^)
echo    If Nom = "" Then
echo    Nom = MyTab(UBound(MyTab^)^)
echo    End if
echo    DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop"^)
echo    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath ^& "\" ^& Nom ^& ".lnk"^)
echo    objShortCut.TargetPath = Dblquote(CheminApplication^)
echo    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = "Winver.exe,0"
echo    objShortCut.Save
echo End Sub
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************
echo ^'Fonction pour ajouter les doubles quotes dans une variable
echo Function DblQuote(Str^)
echo    DblQuote = Chr(34^) ^& Str ^& Chr(34^)
echo End Function
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************
) > %temp%\Shortcutme.vbs
Start /Wait %temp%\Shortcutme.vbs
Del %temp%\Shortcutme.vbs
::****************************************************************************************************
Title DJ Batch Music Player by Hackoo 2015
:menuLOOP
Color 0A & Mode con cols=78 lines=25
echo(
echo        ===============================================================
echo        "/  |  /  |                    /  |                          ";
echo        "$$ |  $$ |  ______    _______ $$ |   __   ______    ______  ";
echo        "$$ |__$$ | /      \  /       |$$ |  /  | /      \  /      \ ";
echo        "$$    $$ | $$$$$$  |/$$$$$$$/ $$ |_/$$/ /$$$$$$  |/$$$$$$  |";
echo        "$$$$$$$$ | /    $$ |$$ |      $$   $$<  $$ |  $$ |$$ |  $$ |";
echo        "$$ |  $$ |/$$$$$$$ |$$ \_____ $$$$$$  \ $$ \__$$ |$$ \__$$ |";
echo        "$$ |  $$ |$$    $$ |$$       |$$ | $$  |$$    $$/ $$    $$/ ";
echo        "$$/   $$/  $$$$$$$/  $$$$$$$/ $$/   $$/  $$$$$$/   $$$$$$/  ";
echo        "                                                            ";
echo        "                                                            ";
echo(       =============================Menu==============================
echo(
for /f "tokens=2* delims=_ " %%A in ('"findstr /b /c:":menu_" "%~f0""') do echo                         %%A  %%B
echo(
echo(       ===============================================================
set choice=
echo( & set /p choice=Make a choice or hit ENTER to quit: || GOTO :EOF
echo( & call :menu_[%choice%]
GOTO:menuLOOP
::********************************************************************************************
:menu_[1] Play DJ Buzz Radio
cls & color 0A
Call:SkipLine 10
Call:Tab 3
echo %x% Please Wait for a while .. Launching DJ Buzz Radio ...
Taskkill /IM "wscript.exe" /F >nul 2>&1
Set vbsfile=%temp%\DJBuzzRadio.vbs
Set URL=http://www.chocradios.ch/djbuzzradio_windows.mp3.asx
Call:Play %URL% %vbsfile%
Start %vbsfile%
TimeOut /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
GOTO:menuLOOP
::********************************************************************************************
:menu_[2] Play David Guetta Mix
cls & color 0A
Call:SkipLine 10
Call:Tab 3
echo %x% Please Wait for a while .. Launching David Guetta Mix ...
Taskkill /IM "wscript.exe" /F >nul 2>&1
Set vbsfile=%temp%\David_Guetta_Miami.vbs
Set URL=http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/David_Guetta_Miami_2014.mp3
Call:Play %URL% %vbsfile%
Start %vbsfile%
TimeOut /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
GOTO:menuLOOP
::********************************************************************************************
:menu_[3] Play Ibiza Mix
cls & color 0A
Call:SkipLine 10
Call:Tab 3
echo %x% Please Wait for a while .. Launching Ibiza Mix ...
Taskkill /IM "wscript.exe" /F >nul 2>&1
Set vbsfile=%temp%\IbizaMix.vbs
Set URL=http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/IbizaMix.mp3
Call:Play %URL% %vbsfile%
Start %vbsfile%
TimeOut /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
GOTO:menuLOOP
::********************************************************************************************
:menu_[4] Play Avicii Mega Mix
cls & color 0A
Call:SkipLine 10
Call:Tab 3
echo %x% Please Wait for a while .. Launching Avicii Megamix ...
Taskkill /IM "wscript.exe" /F >nul 2>&1
Set vbsfile=%temp%\IbizaMix.vbs
Set URL="http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Best of Avicii Megamix 2014.mp3"
Call:Play %URL% %vbsfile%
Start %vbsfile%
TimeOut /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
GOTO:menuLOOP
::********************************************************************************************
:menu_[5] Play Mega Mix 90
cls & color 0A
Call:SkipLine 10
Call:Tab 3
echo %x% Please Wait for a while .. Launching Mega Mix 90 ...
Taskkill /IM "wscript.exe" /F >nul 2>&1
Set vbsfile=%temp%\IbizaMix.vbs
Set URL="http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Megamix 90.mp3"
Call:Play %URL% %vbsfile%
Start %vbsfile%
TimeOut /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
GOTO:menuLOOP
::********************************************************************************************
:menu_[6] Stop the music
cls & color 0C
Call:SkipLine 10
Call:Tab 3
echo  %x% Please Wait for a while .. Stopping the music ...
Taskkill /IM "wscript.exe" /F >nul 2>&1
TimeOut /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
GOTO:menuLOOP
::********************************************************************************************
:Play
(
echo Play "%~1"
echo Sub Play(URL^)
echo    Dim Sound
echo    Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX"^)
echo    Sound.URL = URL
echo    Sound.settings.volume = 100
echo    Sound.Controls.play
echo    do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
echo        wscript.sleep 100
echo    loop
echo    wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000
echo End Sub
)>%~2
::*********************************************************************************************
:Tab
set "x="
For /L %%I In (1,1,%1) Do Set "x=!x!    "
REM                                  ^-- this is a TAB
goto :eof
::*********************************************************************************************
:SkipLine
    For /L %%I In (1,1,%1) Do Echo(
    Goto:Eof
:EOF
EXIT
::*********************************************************************************************
```