# Music file for batch playing too long. Currently using Sacha Dee's code, see below

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

This is my code:

```
@echo off
set "file=TobuMusic.mp3"
( echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
  echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
  echo Sound.Controls.play
  echo do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
  echo wscript.sleep 100
  echo loop
  echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000) >sound.vbs
start /min sound.vbs
```

I've downloaded a song from the music producer 7obu (Tobu) online, and I want to play the song on a batch file. This code helped a lot, but I don't understand how I can make it exactly 10 seconds long.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Maybe you could reference the link to where you got the code.  Also, not understanding why you would use a batch file to create a Vbscript file and then execute the Vbscript.  Why not just do everything in Vbscript?

Comment: you need to check the state of the `Sound` object and to exit forcefully when the state is `1`. [**Here's an example with jscript**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/mediarunner.bat)  hope you'll be able to translate it to vbscript.[More ways](https://www.reddit.com/r/Batch/comments/45jgbh/how_to_play_musicsounds_in_batch/) to play sound through the command line.

Comment: I guess the OP is talking about this post: [Play invisible music with batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23316395)

Comment: @Squashman, http://stackoverflow.com/a/23316395

Comment: I also didn't do VBScript because I want to play a section of text after the music.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I don't understand how I can make it exactly 10 seconds long.**

Simply force your **VB script** to sleep for 10 seconds: instead of

```
wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration)+1)*1000
```

use

```
iMaxDuration = Sound.Currentmedia.Duration + 0.5
If iMaxDuration > 10 Then iMaxDuration = 10
Wscript.Sleep Int( iMaxDuration * 1000 )
Sound.Close
```

In your **batch script**: instead of

```
echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000) >sound.vbs
```

use

```
echo iMaxDuration = Sound.Currentmedia.Duration + 0.5
echo If iMaxDuration ^> 10 Then iMaxDuration = 10
echo Wscript.Sleep Int( iMaxDuration * 1000 ^)
echo Sound.Close) >sound.vbs
```

Comment: @bextem My pleasure. Please consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235) if you find that it solved your problem.