# How to play sound on batch file?

Tags: command-line

How can you play an audio file in a command script?
I wanted to play my gta sa menu sound effect on my launcher at startup but i've run some issues and some errors that keep me from playing the file

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569765/how-to-play-audio-file-on-windows-from-command-line

Comment: Generally it is difficult to help you if you are not more specific. What issues and errors did occur? What have you tried so far?